# Is an AI upscaler incapable of reducing entropy?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, information-theory, entropy

I was reading the description of [Anime4K](https://github.com/bloc97/Anime4K) (a video upscaler software) and I found a statement triggering my attention:

> [upscaling is done] without any meaningful decrease in entropy (lost information
> is lost).

If someone sits down and redraw a cartoon, they may be perfectly capable of using their experience to undo the effect of a terribly lossy compression, inferring lost information pretty much as the author intended it to be. A well-trained AI is capable of the same process, isn't it?

And, even if the reconstruction process adds details which were not in the original, producing a different but more enjoyable result, can we say that we did not have *any meaningful decrease of entropy*?

Comment: Surely you mean increase of entropy? My 'upscaler' that always outputs a black image can reduce your entropy by a lot!

Comment: @orlp Probably yes, I kept the terminology that I found in that readme, which may be imprecise. The idea of the question should be clear anyway.

Comment: (@orlp: Iff confident about *entropy*, consider improving its wiki description. *I* would have assumed "white noise" as an image to have maximal entropy. (And *uniform colour* not much lower.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the AI upscaler algorithm is deterministic, then the entropy of the output $Y=f(X)$ will be *not larger* than the entropy of the input $X$. This is due to the information-theoretic inequality
$$
H(f(X)) \le H(X)
$$
where $H(X)$ is the entropy of $X$, which holds for any random variable $X$ and deterministic algorithm $f$. That is, the entropy of a random variable  can only decrease when that variable is passed through a (deterministic) function ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Further_properties)).

When the upscaler algorithm is randomized, the above relation may not hold: for example, the algorithm could output random white-noise images in response to images that are only fully black or fully white. However, as you can see even in this scenario we are not recovering any meaningful information. We can understand even this case as follows. Let $Z$ be a random variable representing the "ground truth": the high-resolution, ideal image or video. Let us assume that the low-resolution image $X$ that is input to the upscaler depends on $Z$, and that the upscaler can only rely on information in $X$ (it cannot access $Z$ directly). Schematically,
$$
Z \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y
$$
In information theory, this is called a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) of the three random variables $Z$, $X$, and $Y$. Mathematically, it means that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is independent of $Z$.
One basic result of information-theory is that in this setting, the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) $I(Z; Y)$ between the ideal image and the upscaled image can only be lower than the mutual information $I(Z; X)$ between the ideal image and the input to the upscaler:
$$
I(Z; Y) \le I(Z; X)
$$
This is called the [data processing inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality).

Thus, the only possibility if you really want to be able to increase the mutual information between the upscaled image and the ideal image is to have some way to access information in $Z$ that is not in $X$. For example, you might train your upscaling algorithm on a collection of images which you assume will be representative of your ground truth-input pairs $(Z, X)$. If the collection is indeed representative, this gives you the same kind of background knowledge (= experience) that a skilled drawer is using in reconstructing a low-quality drawing. A related problem is the [image inpainting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting) problem in image processing, where damaged, deteriorating, or missing parts of an artwork are filled in to present a complete image.